Dev-C++ terminal window closes right away after I run my code
Every time I run my code, the terminal window closes right away. I have already tried multiple ways to fix it but none of them have worked yet. I aded "getc();" before "return" and it doesn't work anyway. I'm unsure of what to do next.
This is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   getc();
   
   return 0;
}


Just to add, if it matters, at first I had the problem of "Source file not compiled" and I fixed it by deleting "collect2.exe" on the gcc folder. I'm usure if it has anything to do with this but I wanted to comment it.
I have to use this IDE because of university so please someone help me! I expected it to run smoothly after fixing the old problem I already had with the IDE but a new problem popped up.

That's because getc() doesn't compile: error C2198: 'getc': too few arguments for call. You are probably still running the previous code. Try getchar().

Try printf("Press ENTER to terminate\n"); char tmp[100]; fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin); instead of getc();

On an unrelated note, Dev-C++ is old and outdated, and by default comes with an almost as old and outdated compiler. There are better and more modern alternatives for both, both paid and free.

@pmg I tried and it didn't work.

@some-programmer-dude I'm unsure if I can use others since as I mentioned, I need to use Dev-c++ for university.

Where did you get the idea that deleting some tools from compiler folder might solve any problem?

"Source file not compiled" – due to syntax error as mentioned

Someone asked the very same question some week ago. I can't find it though, must have used wrong tags...
